# Conditional expected value on event vs on random variable

Tags: probability

I have to show that:

E(E(g(Y)|X=x)h(X)) =  E(E(g(Y)|X)h(X))

where g(Y) and h(X) are positive, measurable functions.
I don't understand why this should be the same thing... Maybe someone could help me.